# The search bar is set as the header of UITable view but is only half rendered

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableView`, with an xib which contains the search bar. The search bar is connected using IBOutlet and then set as the header. However the search bar is only half visible.

This is how I set the header,

```
aself.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: did you set the header size of the UITableView ?????

Comment: Did you set it as table header or header for section 0 ?

Comment: yes i did set the header size.

Comment: this is what I wrote to set the header : aself.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

Comment: Upload the image to somewhere and share the link. You can use some third party site like http://tinypic.com/

Comment: This is a screenshot of the simulator : [IMG]http://i47.tinypic.com/o8e8a0.png[/IMG]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to completely delete everything on the search bar that I had in the project. I then started fresh on the whole thing and followed an online tutorial. The problem was then fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem would be solved with ScrollView or tableview Auto resize.If Scrollview is not there you should auto resize the tableview.

Comment: it is already a scrollview and 'auto resize subview' too is already enabled